# BCP utility error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select @sql='select * from application.dbo.'+@TableName1+''+char(13)+char(10)+'except'+char(13)+char(10)+'select * from '+'application_check'+'.dbo.'+@TableName1+''

exec sp_executesql  @sql

select @script='bcp sp_executesql  '+@sql+'queryout "D:\SNB\Test\datacheck.txt" -T -c -t "|"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @script
```

> Error: Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format' while trying to export output into a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of fixes:

1. removed all the unnecessary concatenation from the sql query.
2. The SQL Query must be wrapped inside double quotes `"Sql Query"`
3. Execute sp_executesql not required.

### Solution:

```
select @sql='select * from application.dbo.'+ QUOTENAME(@TableName1)
           +'  except  select * from application_check.dbo.'+ QUOTENAME(@TableName1)

SET @script='bcp "'+@sql+'" queryout "D:\SNB\Test\datacheck.txt" -T -c -t "|"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @script
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @sql='select * from application.dbo.'+@TableName1+''+char(13)+char(10)+'except'+char(13)+char(10)+'select * from '+'application_check'+'.dbo.'+@TableName1+''

-- exec sp_executesql  @sql

select @script='bcp "'+@sql+'" queryout "D:\SNB\Test\datacheck.txt" -T -c -t "|"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @script
```

You need not use `sp_executesql`. You can use the query itself.